Do we need a comma between a verb and a participle?
Do we need a comma between a verb and a participle with the same subject?
She waited, standing with a book at the bus stop.

Not just participles: "She waited, cold and hungry."

Not always. Nothing wrong Sometimes, the news was so bad he sat crying in his chair for hours, for example. But don't think in terms of commas. Think in terms of pauses in speech.

Thank you. So, can I write this sentence  without a comma?

She waited, standing with a book in her hand at the bus stop. is a way of writing: She waited and stood with a book in her hand at the bus stop.
You always need a comma with the participle.
They stood in the corner, laughing.
They stood in the corner and laughed.
Whenever the participle phrase modifies a noun or is tacked onto a sentence, you need a comma.
Laughing, she hung up the phone.
She hung up the phone, laughing.

Thank you! Simple and clear.
